# Cannot access the value in one property from another property

Tags: javascript

The following is my code:

```
var Util = {
    parentElement: $('#parent'),
    windowWidth: this.parentElement.width,
    windowHeight: this.parentElement.height,

    init: function() {
        this.selfPlaneElement = this._loadImage('images/self.gif');
        this.enemyPlaneElement = this._loadImage('images/boss.gif');
        this.bulletElement = this._loadImage('images/bullet.jpg');
    },

    _loadImage: function(imgSrc) {
        var e = $('<img>', {
        src: imgSrc
    }).css({'position': 'absolute'});

        return e;
    }
}
```

But when I executed the code, I was told:

> this.parentElement is not defined.

How can I access the property value I gave to 'parentElement'?

Comment: `this` doesn't exist in that context because there's no object to refer to

Comment: is this code being executed in `$(document).ready()` ?  It's possible you're trying to set the variable `Util` before the objects are in the DOM.

Comment: There is a difference between calling "parentElement" and "this.parentElement". Additionally, What jayoaK says above could also be another possibility and additional error.

Comment: No, this code is not executed in $(document).ready(). So if I want to use the value in parentElement, how I can do?

Comment: By using `Util.parentElement`, since `Util` is the name of your object after all.